# AngularJS $resource Error Handing with Callback

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

I have a factory that has multiple services for querying a custom API I built. The callbacks all work, but I'm wondering how I can have any error handling while fetching.

```
.factory('customApiService', function ($resource) {
      return {
          yelp: function (businessId, callback) {
              var api = $resource('../../api/Yelp/:businessId', {
                  businessId: businessId
              }, {
                  fetch: 'JSONP',
                  'query': { isArray: false }
              });

              api.fetch(function (response) {
                  callback(response);
              });
          },
          tripAdvisor: function (hotelId, callback) {
              var api = $resource('../../api/TripAdvisor/:hotelId', {
                  hotelId: hotelId
              }, {
                  fetch: 'JSONP',
                  'query': { isArray: false }
              });

              api.fetch(function (response) {
                  callback(response);
              });
          }
      }
  });
```

And an example of using this factory in a controller:

```
.controller('yelpCtrl', [
  '$scope', 'customApiService', function ($scope, customApiService) {

      customApiService.yelp("yelpIdHere", function (d) {
          //On successful callback run code
      });

      customApiService.tripAdvisor("tripAdvisorIdHere", function (d) {
          //On successful callback run code
      });
   }
])
```

Currently if there is any bad response (404, 500, 504, etc), the callback is not fired.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle $resource service errors in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20584367/how-to-handle-resource-service-errors-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to change my Factory to return an errorCallback as well as a successful callback:

```
.factory('customApiService', function ($resource) {
  return {
      yelp: function (businessId, callback, errorCallback) {
          var api = $resource('../../api/Yelp/:businessId', {
              businessId: businessId
          }, {
              fetch: 'JSONP',
              'query': { isArray: false }
          });

          api.query(function (response) {
              callback(response);
          },
          function (error) {
              errorCallback(error);
          });
      },
      tripAdvisor: function (hotelId, callback, errorCallback) {
          var api = $resource('../../api/TripAdvisor/:hotelId', {
              hotelId: hotelId
          }, {
              fetch: 'JSONP',
              'query': { isArray: false }
          });

          api.query(function (response) {
              callback(response);
          },
          function (error) {
              errorCallback(error);
          });
      }
  }
});
```

So now in the controller, I have a second function as a parameter to my factory calls which will handle any errors:

```
.controller('yelpCtrl', [
  '$scope', 'customApiService', function ($scope, customApiService) {

      customApiService.yelp("yelpIdHere", function (d) {
          //On successful callback run code
      },
      function(e){
          //Do error handling here
      });

      customApiService.tripAdvisor("tripAdvisorIdHere", function (d) {
          //On successful callback run code
      },
      function(e){
          //Do error handling here
      });
   }
])
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20584430/2034230) seemed to help

Answer (score 1):

The solution probably is to use `$promise`. ngResource instances and collections both have `$promise` so instead of working with the `$resource` object use the promise which comes with success, error, finally methods. [see $q doc on angular site](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)