# Default(generic) error handling for angularjs $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, error-handling, promise, ngresource

I want to implement one generic error callback for all methods of my angularjs Resource, which will log "Default Error Handler Log".

**My Resource:**

```
currentNgModule.factory('StatusesResource', function($resource, $timeout){
    var StatusesResource = $resource(get_gui_url_param('company.employee.statuses', true), null, {
            get: {method: 'GET', isArray: true, headers: getGenericHttpHeaders()},
            create: {method: 'POST', isArray: false, headers: getGenericHttpHeaders()},
            $update: {
                method: 'PATCH',
                isArray: false,
                headers: getGenericHttpHeaders(),
                url: get_gui_url_param('company.employee.status.pk', true)
            },
            delete: {
                method: 'DELETE',
                isArray: false,
                headers: getGenericHttpHeaders(),
                url: get_gui_url_param('company.employee.status.pk', true)
            }
        }, false);

    return StatusesResource;
});
```

For example, in result of execution:

```
$log.debug("Calling Resource Get")
StatusesResource.get({employee_pk: pk},
    function(){$log.debug("success")},
    function(){$log.debug("Get error")}
);

$log.debug("Calling Resource Delete")
StatusesResource.get({pk: pk},
    function(){$log.debug("success")},
    function(){$log.debug("Delete error")}
);
```

I want to get following log:

```
Calling Resource Get
Default Error Handler Log
Get error
Calling Resource Delete
Default Error Handler Log
Delete error
```

Hot to implement this default(initial, generic) callbacks(success, error) for ng-resource?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this [using the `interceptor` property of the resource action definition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25770599/39396).  See [the $resource docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) for more.

So:

```
function resourceResponseErrorHandler(response) {
  $log.error("Resource error");
}

currentNgModule.factory('StatusesResource', function($resource, $timeout){
    var StatusesResource = $resource(get_gui_url_param('company.employee.statuses', true), null, {
            get: {method: 'GET', isArray: true, headers: getGenericHttpHeaders(), interceptor: { resonseError: resourceResponseErrorHandler }},
            create: {method: 'POST', isArray: false, headers: getGenericHttpHeaders(), interceptor: { resonseError: resourceResponseErrorHandler }},
            $update: {
                method: 'PATCH',
                isArray: false,
                headers: getGenericHttpHeaders(),
                url: get_gui_url_param('company.employee.status.pk', true),
                interceptor: { resonseError: resourceResponseErrorHandler }
            },
            delete: {
                method: 'DELETE',
                isArray: false,
                headers: getGenericHttpHeaders(),
                url: get_gui_url_param('company.employee.status.pk', true),
                interceptor: { resonseError: resourceResponseErrorHandler }
            }
        }, false);

    return StatusesResource;
});
```